# Is there a way to keep Rector from inlining class references?

Tags: php, namespaces, php-cs-fixer, class-names, rector

I'm using the Rector ruleset `UP_TO_PHP_74` to update a legacy application.

It mostly does a good job, but the problem I'm seeing a lot of is that it's changing

```
...
use My/Namespace/My/Classname;
...
/** @var Guestlist */
private $myVariable;
```

... to this inline, fully qualified class name:

```
private /My/Namespace/My/Classname $myVariable;
```

This is something I do not want. (That's why `use` statements exist!)

Is there a way I can tell Rector to use `use` statements instead of fully qualified inline references?

If not, is there a way I can tell Rector to run everything *other than* the rule that's doing this?

Alternatively, is there a PHP CS Fixer rule that will automatically turn these inline references back into proper use statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to rector config:

`$rectorConfig->importNames();`

(https://getrector.com/documentation/import-names)

Answer (score 3):

**For Auto Import Names:**
rector provide `$rectorConfig->importNames();`

For Single short classes: `$rectorConfig->importShortClasses(false);` based on your requirement you will be able to pass true/false in it

If you have set `Option::AUTO_IMPORT_NAMES` to true, rector is applying this to every analyzed file, even if no real change by a rector was applied to the file.
The reason is that a so-called post-rector is responsible for this, namely the `NameImportingPostRector`.
If you like to apply the Option::AUTO_IMPORT_NAMES only for real changed files, you can configure this.

```php
$parameters->set(Option::APPLY_AUTO_IMPORT_NAMES_ON_CHANGED_FILES_ONLY, true);
```

To Remove unused Imports:
use the phpcs fixer for it

```php
// ecs.php
use PhpCsFixer\Fixer\Import\NoUnusedImportsFixer;
use Symplify\EasyCodingStandard\Config\ECSConfig;

return static function (ECSConfig $ecsConfig): void {
    $ecsConfig->rule(NoUnusedImportsFixer::class);
};
```

Another option is you can use the coding style:
rule `FullyQualifiedNameClassNameImportSkipVoter` It will prevent adding import statements if already there.